# Clean architecture: which layer for a very common module?

Tags: clean-architecture

I have a very common module for report events to multi-platform/service that It looks like

```
class EventReportRepository @Inject constructor(
  private val logServiceADataSource,
  private val logServiceBDataSource
) {
 
  suspend fun sendEvent(evt: String, args: Map<String,String>)
}
```

Many layers may call this module, such as DataSource, Repository, Domain, ViewMode, Presenter.

My question is, Where is the best position for this module? How to reference it for other layers?

Comment: Reporting events from presentation layer (where you transform output into response) or from domain core (where you manage entities) does not seem trivial at first glance, can you elaborate on such scenarios?

Comment: @opel Hi, I see iosched of google define an AnalysisHelper singleton for report events from any layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a module is called from many layers, it would make sense to put it in a separate "**core**" folder

```
|--> lib/
      |--> core/
      |       |--> utility/
      |       |      |--> common_module_a/
      |       |      |--> common_module_b/
      |       |      |...
      |       |--> ...
      |--> features/
      |       |--> feature_a/
      |       |      |--> data_source/
      |       |      |--> repository/
      |       |      |--> domain/
      |       |      |--> view_mode/
      |       |      |--> presenter/
      |       |--> feature_b/
      |       |      |...
```

*Note: I've seen people organise the features in the above way, but also with the layer folders being the top-level ones, containing feature sub-folder for each layer:*

```
|...
|--> layers/
      |--> data_source/
      |       |--> feature_a/
      |       |--> feature_b/
      |--> repository/
      |       |--> feature_a/
      |       |--> feature_b/
      |--> ...
```

In any case, unlike the features/layers folders, I don't believe there's a hard and fast rule on how to organise the core folder. It will really be case-dependent. It may contain:

- modules that are used throughout the layers (like your example)
- contracts that enforce clean architecture (abstract repository/datasoruce classes, etc.)

Here's an [example](https://github.com/ResoCoder/flutter-tdd-clean-architecture-course/tree/master/lib/core) of such an organisation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I like the first pattern,  clean architecture do not restrict the number of layers, maybe we need to define a lower layer below the repository

Comment: good catch, forgot to add the data source layer in the first example.